# Ubuntu 14.04 crashed and mounting failed

Tags: boot, boot-repair, boot-partition

[image: Screenshot]

I installed ubuntu version two days before , but suddenly got this error while booting..
As in the image mounting failed on /root, and the error shows structure to be cleaned.
How can this be recovered.

Comment: You might need to boot to a LiveCD/DVD and run fsck on your drive.  Looks like a failure in your ext4 file system.

Comment: Try typing `fsck -f /dev/sda4` at the initramfs prompt and see if that'll check/repair your file system. If you can't do it there, let me know, and I'll give you full instructions on how to do this.

Comment: I got an error Fsck: not found

Comment: Can you please help me @heynnema

Comment: Did you type upper-case F? The command that I gave is all lower case. If that still doesn't work, let me know.

Comment: I gave lowercase only. That doesn't work

Comment: See my answer, below... let me know if you have problems with doing it.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments...

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted` and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu EXT4 partition
- quit `gparted`
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX` # replacing X with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`